# Request forwarding contains result of the jsf page/bean that does the forward

Tags: jsf, servlets

Having a strange problem with request forwarding from a jsf bean.  The request is being forwarded without any issue.  The forward to url page is showing in the browser correctly except that, at the bottom of the page, it also contains the result of the forward from jsf page.

I've tried perform a response.reset() before doing the forwarding.  But it still not working.

I use Balus's handy LifeCycleListner to see what is going on.  Below is what I see

1. SystemOut     O START PHASE RESTORE_VIEW(1)
2. SystemOut     O END PHASE RESTORE_VIEW(1)
3. SystemOut     O START PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE(6)
4. SystemOut     O manage bean doing Forward
5. SystemOut     O In the forward to app
6. SystemOut     O END PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE(6) => back to Render_reponse phrase

I guess when it comes back to the Render_response phrase, it append the jsf page to the end of the forward to page.

My forwarding code looks like below:

```
public void forwardHttpRequestTo(String url) {
    try {
        HttpServletRequest request = getHttpServletRequest();
        HttpServletResponse response = getHttpServletRespose();
        try {response.reset();} catch (Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();};
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(url);
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        throw (RuntimeException) ex;
    }
}

public HttpServletRequest getHttpServletRequest() {
    return (HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
}

public HttpServletResponse getHttpServletRespose() {
    return (HttpServletResponse)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
}
```

Comment: I'm not having this problem when using redirect.  Unfortunately, I needs to use forward because I need to pass some attributes in the request for the new url.

Comment: Can you show the code where `forwardHttpRequestTo()` is called?

Comment: What's the concrete functional requirement? Why don't you just use JSF builtin navigation facilities? All this code is very unnatural in a JSF application.

Comment: I use Balus's handy LifeCycleListner to see what is going on.  I post the system.out in the orginal post.  It looks like when the forward to app is done, the JSF comes back to the Render_response phrase, which I think is what cause it to append the jsf page to the end of the forward to page.

Comment: @BalusC : How do one perform JSF built in navigation during the first call?  I know how to do that when user click on an action.  But this forward happen during the first call.

Comment: I can explain the problem, but I have the impression that you're going in totally the wrong direction as to solving the concrete functional requirement. Please tell about the problem for which you thought that *this* is the right solution. Then I can post an answer along with the explanation of the problem and ultimately the *right* solution. I'm not interested in posting answers which continue into downward spiral of performing poor practices.

Comment: I'm working with a non jsf legacy app.  This app (1st app) has a list of items for user to select.  When user click on a item (link), it takes user to the 2nd app.  This 2nd app then perform some checking, if item is not valid, it adds an error attribute to the request and forward request back to the 1st app.  I'm working on a project to re-work only the 2nd app, which I rewrite it using jsf.  So, now, when user clicks on the item on the 1st app, it will take user to this new JSF version of 2nd app.  I'm doing the samething of checking for error and forward it back to 1st app.

Comment: Curious. Well, the solution to the concrete problem would be calling `FacesContext#responseComplete()` after the dispatch call. I'm still not sure whether that all is the right solution. The 2nd app in flavor of a web service which is in turn invoked in a fullworthy JSF validator would be a more correct solution.

Comment: Still doing the same thing after adding responseComplete():  New code looks like this: FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().dispatch(url); FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();

Comment: Every where I read seems to indicate that ExternalContext#dispatch or FacesContext.responseComplete should stop jsf lifeCycle from continue to generate the response.  Not sure why mine is not working that way.

Comment: according to doc responseComplete() does this: Signal the JavaServer Faces implementation that the HTTP response for this request has already been generated (such as an HTTP redirect), and that the request processing lifecycle should be terminated as soon as the current phase is completed.

Comment: since this forwarding happened on the initial call, it goes straight from RESTORE_VIEW to RENDER_RESPONSE.  In the RENDER_RESPONSE is where it calls responseComlete().  According to doc, the request processing life cycle should be terminated as soon as the CURRENT PHASE IS COMPLETED.  So, since it is already in RENDER_RESPONSE phase, it continues on to render the response.

Comment: if that is the case, is it true to say to one should never do forwarding during jsf initial call?

Comment: is there a way to change the viewRoot in the jsf 1.1 facesContext during render phase?  I tried createView with a diff viewId and do setViewRoot but it still render the original viewId page.